# UITabBar acts strange in iOS 7, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios7, uitabbaritem

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // for unselected items that are red
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; // for selected items that are green
```

Why is this code not working in iOS 7?

**setTintColor** works but only changes the "selected"-icon's color, not the unselected ones as it did in earlier iOS versions, which is weird ? **setSelectedImageTintColor** does'nt work at all anymore ? Is it realy not possible to color icons as you wish anymore?

Also the **setSelectionIndicatorImage** is not working as intended in the start of the app, what is happening in iOS 7?

Derp herp Apple, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tint, but you can do it with images:

`[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_seleted.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_unselected.png"]];`

Comment: Do I have to do something else? The unselected is working fine for me, but the selected always appears blue or the color of the tabbar tinctColor

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 7 you have to use `setBarTintColor:` to set the background color, with `setTintColor:` now affecting the foreground color.

Comment: setBarTintColor changes nothing, already tried it. This is just strange and messed up :(

Comment: Have you tried setting `barTintColor` on the instance of the tab bar directly, instead of the `UIAppearance` proxy? I haven't had an issue with this when using `-setBarTintColor:`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Adam Waite doesn't work. Method setFinishedSelectedImage under iOS7 ignores the selected image. You need to so it like this:

```
UITabBarItem *item1 = _tabBarController.tabBar.items[0];
item1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"item1"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
item1.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1-selected"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in iOS 7. The tintColor is used for the selected tab image. The selectedImageTintColor is completely ignored. There is no way to tint unselected tab images.

See a discussion on the Apple Developer Forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/851126#851126  about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i (smallerthen)arrayOfTabBarItems.count; i++) {

    NSString *unselectedImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", arrayOfTabBarItems[i]];

    NSString *selectedImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-pressed.png", arrayOfTabBarItems[i]];

    [tabBarCtrl.tabBar.items[i] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:selectedImageName] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:unselectedImageName]];
}
```

This worked for me.